# Почему сайт на Vue.js возвращает 404 страницу?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, router

При разработке используется `vue 3.0.4` и `vue-router 4.0.2`

Роутер настроен стандартно:

```
{
  path: '/',
  component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
},
{
  path: '/about',
  component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
}
```

Сайт располагается на **GitHub Pages** по адресу `user.github.io/sitename/`

Если зайти на сайт по адресу `user.github.io/sitename/`, и затем по ссылке со страницы **Home** перейти на страницу `user.github.io/sitename/about`, то страница **About** отображается

Если же в адресной строке браузера сразу попытаться перейти по адресу `user.github.io/sitename/about`, то отображается **404 страница GitHub Pages**

В файле `vue.config.js` прописал `publicPath: '/sitename/'`, но не помогло

Подскажите, почему такое может происходить, и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы переходите по `user.github.io/sitename/`, веб-сервер GH Pages отдаёт index.html, включающий в себя информацию о скриптах и стилях - таким образом запускается vue-приложение. После запуска приложения корректно работает vue-router и `user.github.io/sitename/about` становится доступен.

Но при прямом заходе на `user.github.io/sitename/about` веб-сервер не знает, какой файл ему отдать - там нет index.html. Поэтому и возвращается 404 ошибка.

Я не уверен, что можно сконфигурировать веб-сервер GH Pages так, чтобы он на любой запрос отдавал index.html из корня приложения, зато можно настроить работу vue-роутера с **history mode** на **hash**. Для этого достаточно при конфигурировании роутера заменить `history` на `hash`:

`const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'hash', routes: [...] })`

[Больше информации о конфигурировании роутера](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#mode)

[Описание проблемы в доке vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/deployment.html#%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-history-pushstate)

[Описание history mode в доке vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Буду более внимательно изучать документацию